# Concatenate every four files, Linux

Tags: linux, bash, concatenation

I have two files stored with lists of file names:

```
FileA:
GSM1328513
GSM1328514
GSM1328515
GSM1328516
GSM1328545
GSM1328546
GSM1328547
GSM1328548
GSM1328609
GSM1328610
GSM1328611
GSM1328612

and:
FileB:
    Brn
    Hrt
    Lng
```

What I want to do is, concatenate every four files listed in the fileA and name the concatenated file as the file names listed in fileB:
To do it manually, it looks like:

```
cat GSM1328513 GSM1328514 GSM1328515 GSM1328516 > Brn
cat GSM1328545 GSM1328546 GSM1328547 GSM1328548 > Hrt
cat GSM1328609 GSM1328610 GSM1328611 GSM1328612 > Lng
```

Since I have a long list of files, I want to do it automatically, could anyone help.
In case anything not clear, please point out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another quick way to do it without `sed`:

```
cat FileA | while read a ; do read b ; read c ; read d ;
    echo "cat $a $b $c $d > " ; done | paste - FileB | bash
```

As Didier Trosset said, you can skip the `| bash` to see what it does before executing it.

Other approach: one-liner without eval, combining @dshepherd solution with mine:

```
cat FileA | xargs -n4 echo | paste - FileB | while read a b c d e ; do cat $a $b $c $d > $e ; done
```

Advantages: this is the only one-liner so far which does not eval any output (`| bash`) and does not use temporary files, and only uses standard tools found everywhere (`cat`, `xargs`, `paste`).

Comment: I figured out another way at the same time! :) Your method is probably simpler though. I need to start using `while` loops more.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Shell script to do what you want to do

```
iter=0
while read filename
do
    stop=`expr \( $iter + 1 \) \* 4`
    iter=`expr $iter + 1`
    files=`head -n $stop fileA | tail -n 4 | tr '\n' ' '`
    cat $files > $filename
done < fileB
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach: you can easily generate groups of four filenames using

```
cat FileA | xargs -n4 echo
```

However I can't think of any especially elegant way to combine this with the output filenames from FileB. One possibility is to do some string manipulation then eval it (like Didier Trosset's answer).

*Edit:* got it! Using GNU parallel (which is like xargs on steroids):

```
parallel < tempA -n4 -k --files cat | paste - tempB | xargs -n 2 mv
```

the `parallel` command runs cat on each group of 4 arguments and puts the output into temp files. It writes the names of these temp files to stdout (and `-k` means they are written out in the correct order).

`paste` inserts the desired filenames into the stream, then we just use `xargs -n 2 mv` to move the temp files to the desired locations.

I used `< tempA` instead of `cat tempA` because it's technically [best practice](http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html#cat).

The advantage (in my opinion) of this over the other one liners is that you don't have to eval strings (e.g. using `bash`).

Comment: You could also use `paste` at the end: `cat FileA | xargs -n4 echo cat | paste -d '>' - FileB | bash`.  I think this is the shortest answer :)

Comment: I really want to find a one liner that doesn't involve evaling strings but I just can't think of how to do it. I think we need some way to pass independent lists of arguments to `xargs`, but you can't...

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{ORS=(NR%4?" ":"\n")}1' FileA | awk '{print "cat "$0" > "}' | paste - FileB | bash
```

Alternatively, using `dshepherd` method for the first step:

```
xargs -n4 echo < FileA | awk '{print "cat "$0" >"}' | paste - FileB | bash
```

I find these very clean, extensible and logical.

Simplest of all (though a less versatile method, and IMO less "pretty"), is prepending `"cat"` for each `xargs` grouping, and appending `>` as a the delimiter in the `paste` command:

```
 xargs -n4 echo cat < FileA | paste -d ">" - FileB | bash
```

---

Explanation:

1. Using `awk`, make each group of four lines into a single row.
   If the record number, `RN` is modulo four, separate with new line `"\n"`, otherwise a single space space `" "`.
   This gives output:

   ```
   $ awk '{ORS=(NR%4?" ":"\n")}1' FileA
   GSM1328513 GSM1328514 GSM1328515 GSM1328516
   GSM1328545 GSM1328546 GSM1328547 GSM1328548
   GSM1328609 GSM1328610 GSM1328611 GSM1328612
   ```

   As suggested by `dshepherd`, this is easier done with `xargs`:

   ```
   $ xargs -n4 < FileA
   GSM1328513 GSM1328514 GSM1328515 GSM1328516
   GSM1328545 GSM1328546 GSM1328547 GSM1328548
   GSM1328609 GSM1328610 GSM1328611 GSM1328612
   ```
2. Now, for each of these lines, prepend with `cat` and append `>`.

   ```
   $ xargs -n4 < FileA | awk '{print "cat "$0" > "}' 
   cat GSM1328513 GSM1328514 GSM1328515 GSM1328516 > 
   cat GSM1328545 GSM1328546 GSM1328547 GSM1328548 > 
   cat GSM1328609 GSM1328610 GSM1328611 GSM1328612 >
   ```
3. Join each of these lines, with the line from `FileB`, using `paste - FileB` (the `-` meaning to get from standard input.

   ```
   $ xargs -n4 < FileA | awk '{print "cat "$0" > "}' | paste - FileB
   cat GSM1328513 GSM1328514 GSM1328515 GSM1328516 >   Brn
   cat GSM1328545 GSM1328546 GSM1328547 GSM1328548 >   Hrt
   cat GSM1328609 GSM1328610 GSM1328611 GSM1328612 >   Lng
   ```
4. Execute each of these lines as `bash` commands, by piping to `bash`:

   ```
   xargs -n4 < FileA  | awk '{print "cat "$0" > "}' | paste - FileB | bash
   ```

---

Answer (score 1):

One liner:

```
cat FileA | sed 'N;N;N;s/\n/ /g;s/^/cat /;s/$/ >/;' | paste - FileB | bash
```

And you can test what commands will actually be generated by removing the last pipe to `bash`.

For each line of `FileA`, get the next three `N`, convert line feeds `\n` to spaces , prepend `cat`, and append `>`. Then merge each generated line `-` with a line from `FileB`. Send these commands to `bash`.

---

Even shorter `sed`, adding `cat` and `>` in a single replace command.

```
cat FileA | sed 'N;N;N;s/\n/ /g;s/.*/cat & >/;' | paste - FileB | bash
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `bash` arrays (`bash` 4 or later required). I'm also assuming that the number
of names in `fileB` match up with the number of names in `fileA`.

```
readarray -t gsms < FileA
for ((i=0; i<${#gsms[@]}; i+=4)); do
    read fname
    echo "${gsms[@]:i:4}" > "$fname"
done < FileB
```